# Getting smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused while sending email via python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

I am a newbie to python and trying to read the email addresses from a text file, concatenating 100 email addresses and trigger an email from an outlook mailbox to all those concatenated email addresses by keeping them in bcc. Hoping to increase the limit to 500 to 600 in future as bcc field is capable to hold around 700 email addresses.

While testing this script, I faced an issue if I concatenate more than 5 email addresses.

> raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
>
> smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (421, b'4.7.0 Too many protocol errors (6) on this connection, closing transmission channel.')}

The code template is given below. While googling I have noticed that the bcc field should be a list, where I am assigning a string of concatenated emails. Could this be the only reason or will there be any other possibilities?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

Recipient=""
message="Sample email content"

def TriggerEmail():  # connecting with outlook mailbox and trigger email by having 100 email addresses in bcc
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtpserver.org.net', port=587)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo()

    smtpserver.login('mailbox_user_id','mailbox_password')
    emailFrom = 'Mailbox_name@org.com'
    global Recipient
    global message
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = emailFrom
    msg['Bcc'] = Recipient
    msg['Subject'] = "Sample Email Subject"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message,'plain'))
    smtpserver.send_message(msg)
    del msg
    smtpserver.quit()

def main():
    intCount = 0
    flg = True
    global Recipient
    with open("EmailAddresses.txt", "r") as f:  #reading hundreads of email addresses from the text file (one row has one email address)
        for line in f:
            if intCount < 100: # concatenating 100 email addresses and then trigger email once 100 email addresses are concatenated
                if Recipient == "":
                    Recipient = line.strip()
                else:
                    Recipient += "," + line.strip()
                intCount += 1
                flg = True
            else:
                TriggerEmail()
                Recipient = line.strip()
                intCount = 1
                flg = False
        if (flg):
            TriggerEmail()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am using Python 3.6. I tried running the script from Git bash and also via Anaconda (using Spyder).

Appreciate your help!

Thanks.

Comment: I have tested a close version of your code against Python standard library `smtpd.DebuggingServer`. I can confirm that if Bcc is a string of 100 addresses delimited with commas, smtplib actually send 100 `RCPT TO` commands to the server. So AFAIK the Python part is correct. But are you sure that your mail server can accept so many recipients? Most will not in order to limit the risk of SPAM.You should first try with a reasonable number (5 to 10 recipients).

Comment: Thank you Serge. I tried with 5 email addresses as a limit and it was successful. I spoke to the messaging team on the limit of bcc before coming up with the code.. but as you mentioned, there could be a restriction at messaging server side. Will check with them..